# Is it possible to load local Javascript libraries to an online page on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari, uiwebview

We gonna implement a hybrid App that uses built in Safari views (UIWebView) to handle some social stuff. We are to use some smart Javascript libraries to handle some UI stuff on the pages, and we don't want to load the libraries from the servers all the time.

Is it possible to pack some *.js into the application bundle, then access it during browsing? Hope you can understand my question.

If this "hybrid mode" works, maybe we could pack some common UI *.png-s, too.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can, you have a couple of possibilities, like:

1. You have the -stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: method on the UIWebView - and i believe you can execute the content of your js files ... I'm not sure, never tried it though ... but it should work.
2. you can create a subclass of NSURLProtocol and register your subclass for the http:// schema. This way your class can act as a proxy between the internet and any components that use the http:// schema - and you could return the js and png files from a local cache.
3. you could download separately the html content, and replace the links to local file:// links, then use UIWebView to show this formatted string.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
NSString *jsLibFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"library" ofType:@"js"];
if (jsLibFile) {
    NSString *libSrcTxt = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:jsLibFile];
    if (libSrcTxt) {
        webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:libSrcTxt;
    }
}
```

(Opening the file, and evaluating the JS within webView.)